# XStream ignoring first propery's alias

Tags: web-services, xml-serialization, xstream

I've been struggling with an issue for more than 6 hours and searching for the issue on the web is not being much of help.

There's this class which I use to generate a XML (`XStream` from Thoughworks). It works fine everywhere within the application, except for one class. The ALIAS are annotated in the class and the very first property, no matter which it is, its ALIAS is ignored.

Here is the class:

```java
@XStreamAlias("FNCGRAVAPREMATRICULATITULAR")
public class PreMatriculaTitular {

    @XStreamAlias("NOME")
    private String nome;

    @XStreamAlias("NASCIMENTO")
    private Date nascimento;

    @XStreamAlias("SEXO")
    private String sexo;

    @XStreamAlias("CIV_CODIGO")
    private Integer civCodigo;
              .
              .
              .
```

But the XML generated is:

```xml
<FNCGRAVAPREMATRICULATITULAR>
    <nome>QA click</nome>
    <NASCIMENTO>17091989</NASCIMENTO>
    <SEXO>M</SEXO>
    <CIV_CODIGO>1</CIV_CODIGO>
              .
              .
              .
```

Somehow `XStream` is ignoring the first field's ALIAS. I tried moving fields up and down and it always happens with the first property, no matter which it is.

The whole project is built using `XStream` and `@XStreamAlias` so I cannot change the way things are done. I must use `XStream` and annotation.

`XStream` version is 1.4.7, Java 1.6 with Spring and other gadgets.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: a similar question/answer (not sure if duplicate). It might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702318/spring-mvc-3-2-xstreamalias-ignored

Comment: Hello. My problem is beyond that, the whole thing was working fine until I added a new field to the class. Then it started behaving like this. Even though I remove the added field the behaviour wouldn't change. In my case it is not a bean but it is used within web-services calls.

Comment: Have you tried changing the order of the declarations in the class to see if it has anything to do with order? What happens if you place `nascimento` before `nome`? Does the same thing happen to `nascimento`?

Comment: Yes it does, and NOME comes up fine.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug, but it sure looks like one. To be sure it's not a configuration problem you could write a minimal app with just one class and two or three fields and see if the problem continues to happen. You can also try a workaround. Last time I used `XStream` was almost a decade ago and there were no annotations, but you could use the `XStream` object and call `xstream.aliasField("NOME", PreMatriculaTitular.class, "nome")`. It might be a workaround. You might also try using a field key sorter. But first see if it fails with a minimal example. If not, check your configs.

Comment: Thanks helderdarocha. I have a bunch of other XML files being generated just like this. It works both ways, marshall and unmarshall. I thought about creating a first dummy field which won't be exported. It does sound like a bug, I updated from 1.4.2 originally used in the project to 1.4.7, so if it is a bug it is still there. Will post my tests results here, thanks a million.

Comment: As a dirty workaround, I created a first field like this: @XStreamOmitField private boolean dummy; and the annotation is simply ignored by XStream. Anyway the web service ignores unknown fields and everything else works fine. I'll leave this question open so people can comment on a solution.